# Should I generate html form?

Tags: forms

I'm building a php application that will have many modules/plugins. The issue is that creating smarty template for form's of each plugin and writing validation code for each looks redundant and at the same time using PHP to generate form will restrict the flexibility in controlling each form's layout structure the way I would have wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP classes and inheritance you can write the validation and layout code once and overriding them whenever you need specific behaviour.